# search and replace  block in python

Tags: python, string

I have a config(text) file with the following content :

```
hello {
    if name == "foo" {

       //do something
    else {
       // something else
    }
 # contents 
 }


world {
   if name == "bar" {
       //do something
    else {
       // do something else 
     }
   # comments 
 }
```

I want to search in this file all the if else blocks with "foo". What is the best way in python ?

Comment: Using configuration files that are custom-made Turing complete programming languages is generally a bad idea. Avoid going down this route if possible. Turn back now.

Comment: Turing complete config files are kind of evil. What format is this? Isn't there a library to read or create those configurations?

Answer (score 0):

The comments warning you away from overly complex languages for configuration aren't wrong. But if this is something you must do, the next step is to build a parser that can read your grammar, and give you the token tree. Perhaps something lie [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) would be useful?